# FT230XS USB Bridge not working

Tags: usb, design, uart, ftdi

I designed a small board that needed the capability of communicating over USART, so I threw in an [FT230XS USB|USART Bridge](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT230X.pdf). The device use is so simple that I am out of ideas for troubleshooting.

Looking over the datasheet we can find a suggested bus-powered configuration
[image]

I placed the device on my board exactly as they have don here, minus some of the bus filtering
[image]

I have measured connectivity between the USB side and the 27R resistor, as well as the FT230Xs side and the 27R resistor. I also get all the expected voltages around the device, including the 3.3V output shown in the diagram below. Everything is as expected, it's just that nothing actually happens when I plug the device into a usb port.

I have tried plugging the device into both a Win8 machine and a linux box, but nothing happens. Both machines have the appropriate drivers installed to my knowledge.

The interesting thing here, though, is that no only do the devices not attempt enumeration with the usb stack of the host machine, but they do not do *anything*. I put a scope on either side of the 27R resistor and no data appears to be going through. Namely, the FTDI chip is not attempting to identify itself on powerup, so the host machine obviously is not aware of anything having been hot-plugged.

Is there anything immediately wrong with the design? Are there some additional steps to getting the FT chips to work? After the first FT chip would not enumerate I figured I may have damaged it at some point. Since I ordered three it was no big deal. I used my heat gun to remove the first and solder the second. Again, the second chip demonstrated the same behavior (or lack there of). I then went on to change out the chip a third time, but once again nothing is working.

Comment: That USB micro-B connector seems a little strange to me. It should have 5 pins in this order: 1 VBUS, 2 D-, 3 D+, 4 ID, 5 GND + the shield pins..

Comment: @m.Alin, the footprint I used does have 5 pads, but the ID pin is not connected to anything.

Comment: So don't you use ferrite bead and capacitor for filtering? I think that is the problem. The other thing is C8 should 100nF.

Comment: @Oka, I would consider these as issues as well, but the FT chip never drivers D+ or D- at all on powerup. The only output I am getting from the chip is the 3.3V.

Comment: have you read this errata? http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_139_FT230X%20Errata%20Technical%20Note.pdf
This chip has problems with some USB 3.0 hosts

Comment: Try to make an external pullup for D+ (1.5 kOhm, to the 3V3OUT pin). Maybe the problem is in internal pullup.

Comment: @Oka, I was not aware of that, thank you. Although, the problem is that the FT chip never does *anything*. The problem is not that it cannot enumerate or data transfer results in an error, the chip just sits idly and does nothing when powered.

Comment: Have you check that you have the correct power at VCC and 3V3OUT?? Maybe your connector pinout is incorrect your devices is not even getting powered.

Comment: I did what you did, the same design, but I got what you got :) . after checking the datasheet, I found that the footprint was wrong i.e I created QFN footprint on SSOP footprint so the the pin order was wrong. check this, it might useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make an external pullup for D+ (1.5 kOhm, to the 3V3OUT pin). Maybe the problem is in internal pullup.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late response. But I'll write down my experience of solving it.
I encountered the same issue of the host(PC) not recognizing the FT230X evaluation board.
I found this document and it says that FT230X can function as VCP (Virtual COM Port) or D2XX application. D2xx is the a proprietary interface specifically for FTDI devices and therefore it is configured for D2xx by default.
[image: Windows CDM Architecture]

We can change this configuration using FT Prog software. A screenshot is attached below.
[image]

We can see a COM port detected after programming the FT230X using FT Prog software. Problem Solved!

Comment: This cannot the the solution to the problem, because the chip does not enumerate, so it cannot be configured with FT Prog.